# A virtualbox machine with name "petalandstem" already exists. but actually I deleted all virtual machines

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am facing problem with virtual machine. I have installed virtual box machine with **vagrant up** command, However I deleted entire project but still I am not able to create project with same name.It gives me following error.

```
A VirtualBox machine with the name 'petalandstem' already exists.
Please use another name or delete the machine with the existing
name, and try again.
```

I tried to change UID but it is still not working. How to completely remove project entirely..

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sudo virtualbox
```

and you will have all your virtual machines listed in virtualbox